# How can I view my recent device activity?

Tags: windows-10, monitoring

A little while ago, I went on a 2 <sup>1</sup>/<sub>2</sub> hour bike ride, and when I got back, I noticed that a few applications had been opened on my laptop, that I had not left open when I left. There were a few people around, and I was suspicious that they might have been using my laptop.

Is there a way to view recent device like activity? I'd like too see things such as:

- When applications were opened and closed.
- When the device was being actively used.
- When apps were being actively used.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes its possible to track that sort of info in several ways.

One good way could be with the usage of a third party application which informs you about the general computer activity, such as **LastActivityView** of **Nirsoft**.

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/computer_activity_view.html

[image]

It is freeware.

Answer (score 2):

I would just add in future its wise to consider protecting your laptop to block others from being able interact with it in the first place.
For example, setting the screensaver to lock on resume, disable user switching, disable RDP, ensuring all users have a password, increasing your firewall levels etc... etc...